# cordova media plugin stopped working on Android 6

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I have an application on Google Play that streams music from a radio station built with the latest cordova (5.4) and I am using some of the basic plugins such as:

- device plugin
- crosswalk webview plugin
- dialogs plugin
- ...
- files plugin
- media plugin

On Android 5.0+ the streaming works fine but recently when I upgraded my nexus on android 6.0 the streaming stopped. I updated media and file plugin to the latest versions (2.0.0 and 4.0.0 respectively), as cordova stated in their blog that these versions support the new permission checking on Android 6 but still the streaming is not working. The log gives me this:

```
11-24 23:53:35.347 15184-15184/com.uni.app E/chromium: [ERROR:xwalk_autofill_client.cc(170)] Not implemented reached in virtual void xwalk::XWalkAutofillClient::OnFirstUserGestureObserved()
11-24 23:53:40.395 15184-15235/com.uni.app D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
11-24 23:53:40.410 15184-15235/com.uni.app W/MediaPlayer: Stream has no duration and is therefore not seekable.
11-24 23:53:40.410 15184-15235/com.uni.app E/MediaPlayer: error (-2147483648, 0)
11-24 23:53:40.410 15184-15235/com.uni.app D/AudioPlayer: Send a onStatus update for the new seek
11-24 23:53:40.410 15184-15235/com.uni.app W/CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send a second callback for ID: Media951412725 Result was: {"action":"status","status":{"id":"d5334ff7-5511-ea09-b2ef-2900789941a9","msgType":3,"value":0}}
11-24 23:53:40.411 15184-15235/com.uni.app E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 0
11-24 23:53:40.411 15184-15235/com.uni.app E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
11-24 23:53:40.412 15184-15235/com.uni.app W/CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send a second callback for ID: Media951412725 Result was: {"action":"status","status":{"id":"d5334ff7-5511-ea09-b2ef-2900789941a9","msgType":1,"value":2}}
11-24 23:53:40.412 15184-15235/com.uni.app E/MediaPlayer: Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
11-24 23:53:40.412 15184-15235/com.uni.app E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
11-24 23:53:40.412 15184-15235/com.uni.app W/CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send a second callback for ID: Media951412725 Result was: {"action":"status","status":{"id":"d5334ff7-5511-ea09-b2ef-2900789941a9","msgType":2,"value":314586.9375}}
11-24 23:53:40.413 15184-15235/com.uni.app E/MediaPlayer: Error (-2147483648,0)
11-24 23:53:40.413 15184-15235/com.uni.app D/AudioPlayer: on completion is calling stopped
11-24 23:53:40.414 15184-15235/com.uni.app W/CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send a second callback for ID: Media951412725 Result was: {"action":"status","status":{"id":"d5334ff7-5511-ea09-b2ef-2900789941a9","msgType":1,"value":4}}
11-24 23:53:40.414 15184-15235/com.uni.app E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
11-24 23:53:40.414 15184-15235/com.uni.app D/AudioPlayer: on completion is calling stopped
11-24 23:53:40.414 15184-15235/com.uni.app E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
11-24 23:53:40.414 15184-15235/com.uni.app D/AudioPlayer: on completion is calling stopped
11-24 23:53:53.476 15184-15184/com.uni.app E/chromium: [ERROR:xwalk_autofill_client.cc(170)] Not implemented reached in virtual void xwalk::XWalkAutofillClient::OnFirstUserGestureObserved()
11-24 23:53:58.409 15184-15232/com.uni.app E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaed05f70
11-24 23:53:58.419 15184-15184/com.uni.app W/ScreenOrientationListener: Removing an inexistent observer!
11-24 23:53:58.419 15184-15184/com.uni.app E/chromium: [ERROR:runtime_javascript_dialog_manager.cc(69)] Not implemented reached in virtual void xwalk::RuntimeJavaScriptDialogManager::ResetDialogState(content::WebContents*)
11-24 23:53:58.453 15184-15184/com.uni.app D/AudioPlayer: renaming /storage/emulated/0/tmprecording.3gp to /storage/emulated/0/http://IPADDRESS:PORT/;
11-24 23:53:58.454 15184-15184/com.uni.app E/AudioPlayer: FAILED renaming /storage/emulated/0/tmprecording.3gp to /storage/emulated/0/http://IPADDRESS:PORT/;
11-24 23:53:58.465 15184-15197/com.uni.app E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb3978f90
```

IPADDRESS:PORT is a real http://ipaddress:port URL stream which works fine.

I now it has to do with the permissions but still no luck on finding exactly what. Going on app-info and on new permissions menu I see that the app uses Microphone, Phone and Storage permissions which are all enabled. I searched a lot and couldn't be able to find something similar.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: which media plugin version are you using? today a new version was released with android 6 support

Comment: @jcesarmobile I answer that in my question. It's media v2.0.0 this is the version cordova released to support android 6.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't read that. Can you show the code you are using? You say it isn't crosswalk, but the errors you show are related to crosswalk, can you show the errors that appear if you remove crosswalk?

Comment: The errors that appear have to do with the media element. Removing crosswalk I get the same log without the 2-3 lines related to crosswalk errors. The code is as described in cordova documentation on how to use the media plugin (working fine on Android 5+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked on Github in the official repo and found [this](https://github.com/lucViana/cordova-plugin-media/commit/b6da930531d556e5541dade40d9ba679694c951b)

Tried on a new sample app and worked fine on my Android 6.0 device. The solution is close to what luckakashi suggested with some extra commenting.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, just comment this line on AudioPlayer.java

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
    // Listen for playback completion
    this.player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    // seek to any location received while not prepared
    //this.seekToPlaying(this.seekOnPrepared);
    // If start playing after prepared
    if (!this.prepareOnly) {
        this.player.start();
        this.setState(STATE.MEDIA_RUNNING);
        this.seekOnPrepared = 0; //reset only when played
    } else {
        this.setState(STATE.MEDIA_STARTING);
    }
    // Save off duration
    this.duration = getDurationInSeconds();
    // reset prepare only flag
    this.prepareOnly = true;

    // Send status notification to JavaScript
    sendStatusChange(MEDIA_DURATION, null, this.duration);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems something wrong from Crosswalk, have you try if you remove the Crosswalk plugin? And is your Android 6.0 device 64-bit?

Comment: Hi, it's not on crosswalk plugin. I tried removing crosswalk and I get the exact same log but without the messages about crosswalk . it's the media element and files plugin that fails.